# PySide2 cannot find a Qt dependency while building a PyInstaller

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pyinstaller, pyside2

While building my PySide2 project a Qt error occurs, but I already have installed Qt in my system.

I tried building the project in Windows, which occurs just fine, giving it a Dll error -- because my project use one --; but the code itself run just fine in Windows or Linux.

```sh
...
22440 INFO: Loading module hooks...
22440 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-httplib2.py"...
22441 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PySide2.QtGui.py"...
22550 WARNING: Cannot read QLibraryInfo output: raised Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) when decoding:
False
22550 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PySide2.QtWidgets.py"...
22551 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
22552 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
22554 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
22555 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-clr.py"...
22555 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
22707 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
22792 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
22802 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PySide2.QtNetwork.py"...
22802 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-appdirs.py"...
22805 INFO: Excluding import 'win32com'
22807 INFO:   Removing import of win32com from module appdirs
22807 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-cryptography.py"...
23128 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PySide2.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==4.0.dev0+gffb1ff36', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "/home/farm/Documents/ActionLicenses/main.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 243, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 502, in assemble
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/imphook.py", line 410, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/imphook.py", line 377, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/compat.py", line 793, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 407, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 907, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 732, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-PySide2.py", line 18, in <module>
    collect_system_data_files(pyside2_library_info.location['PrefixPath'],
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/hooks/qt.py", line 89, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError
```

I would like to know how to understand better this error to fix it.

Comment: Any resolution to this? I am also finding this same issue.